# Login to umbraco 7 backoffice from external console application

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have console application that need's to access Umbraco backoffice custiom page, but to access this page console application needs to login first.

Is there a way for external console application to login to umbraco backoffice?

Comment: What do you want to do in the backoffice?

Comment: Are you using 7.3? Then what do you need from a custom backoffice page that you can't recreate using either the REST API or by making and calling your own API controller inside the solution?